# how to assign a key in object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to total all same ID and assign a specific key

```
var ingredArray= [{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":222},{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":33},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":424},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":22},{"inventory_id":3,"pergram":400},{"inventory_id":5,"pergram":200}]
    
let deduction={};
ingredArray.forEach(function (item) {
     if (deduction.hasOwnProperty(item.inventory_id)) {
          deduction[item.inventory_id] = deduction[item.inventory_id] + parseFloat(item.pergram);
      } else {
          deduction[item.inventory_id] = parseFloat(item.pergram);
      }
});

console.log(deduction);
```

> this is the result of my code

```
{1: 255, 2: 446, 3: 400, 5: 200}
```

> I want to achieve

```
{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":255},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":446},{"inventory_id":3,"pergram":400},{"inventory_id":5,"pergram":200}
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the `ingredArray` and the final result that you want. As for your `deduction` vs the final result, that's not possible in a dictionary, it should have a proper `key` and a `value`. What you want as the final result is a sort of an array, and it looks exactly the same as `ingredArray`

Comment: There are two objects with the same key. The OP wants to integrate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var ingredArray = [{ "inventory_id": 1, "pergram": 222 }, { "inventory_id": 1, "pergram": 33 }, { "inventory_id": 2, "pergram": 424 }, { "inventory_id": 2, "pergram": 22 }, { "inventory_id": 3, "pergram": 400 }, { "inventory_id": 5, "pergram": 200 }]
           

var helper = {};
let deduction = ingredArray.reduce(function (r, o) {
var key = o.inventory_id;
    
if (!helper[key]) {
   helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
   r.push(helper[key]);
} else {
   helper[key].pergram += o.pergram;
}
    
  return r;
}, []);
    
console.log(deduction);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array of objects building a new object of summed values based on key, and then grab the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const data = [{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":222},{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":33},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":424},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":22},{"inventory_id":3,"pergram":400},{"inventory_id":5,"pergram":200}];

const out = data.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Grab the id and pergram variables from the
  // new object in the iteration
  const { inventory_id: id, pergram } = c;

  // If the the accumulator object doesn't have a key that
  // matches the id create a new new object, and set the
  // pergram variable to zero
  acc[id] = acc[id] || { inventory_id: id, pergram: 0 };

  // And then add the pergram value to the
  // pergram object property
  acc[id].pergram += pergram;

  // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map` to store the object reference based on unique `inventory_id` and call `Array.reduce()` method over list of objects.

```js
var ingredArray= [{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":222},{"inventory_id":1,"pergram":33},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":424},{"inventory_id":2,"pergram":22},{"inventory_id":3,"pergram":400},{"inventory_id":5,"pergram":200}];

const processArray = (list) => {
  const map = new Map();
  return list.reduce((accumulator, obj) => {
    const inventory = map.get(obj.inventory_id);
    if (inventory) {
      inventory.pergram += obj.pergram;
    } else {
      accumulator.push(obj);
      map.set(obj.inventory_id, obj);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}

console.log(processArray(ingredArray));
```